# ImportError: No module named controller_manager_msgs.srv on RRBot Ros_Control Example

Tags: ros, gazebo-1.9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I have been trying to go through the rrbot_gazebo example, having made it as far as the section on control.

However I seem to be stuck at one point. Running the command
'`roslaunch rrbot_control rrbot_control.launch` '

It is here that the spawner from `catkin_ws/src/ros_control/controller_manager/scripts/spawner`, fails giving an error

```
 File "/home/user/catkin_ws/src/ros_control/controller_manager/scripts/spawner", line 43, in <module> from controller_manager_msgs.srv import *
ImportError: No module named controller_manager_msgs.srv
```

I'm not sure why as the folder controller_manager/srv exists and contains numerous .srv files.

I have run catkin_make beforehand and everything runs / builds smoothly.

I'm on Ubuntu Raring, have installed ROS Hydro Quantal however, and Gazebo Quantal. But then again i see the same problem on another computer which has raring for everything.

Any possible Ideas? I understand that the RRBot example is in flux due to Hydro, so is incomplete, but any help is appreciated.

Cdr

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4043/importerror:-no-module-named-controller_manager_msgs.srv-on-rrbot-ros_control-example/) by [Cdrwolfe](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/454/cdrwolfe/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-08-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Try:

```
git clone https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_controllers.git
```

From you catkin/src folder.

And `catkin_make` again after.

You will also probably need:

```
git clone https://github.com/ros-controls/control_toolbox.git
git clone https://github.com/ros-controls/realtime_tools.git
```

---

Originally posted by [Arn-O](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/416/arn-o/) with karma: 316 on 2013-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cdrwolfe](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/454/cdrwolfe/) on 2013-08-06**:
Thanks, I think I had them at the time but didn't catkin_make, or possibly forgot to add source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash to bash.src